# Boolean Menu Validation

Tags: java, validation, return, boolean

[image]

I'm trying to make a menu to ask the user to input YES or NO, if none of their input is either that, I want to prompt the user the question again. I was wondering why the code needs another return statement.

Answer (score 2):

You code is wrong

1. You need to prompt again within the loop, otherwise if you do not eneter Yes or No, it will just spin forever.
2. When getting the `nextLine` you need to assign to a variable ,else it is just lost.
3. The value for valid never changes

so you code should be something like

```
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
     boolean yes = false;
     while (true) {
         System.out.println("enter yes or no");
         String line = sc.nextLine();
         if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
             yes = true;
             break;
         }
         if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
             break;
         }
         // else back to the top
     }
     
     return yes;
```